# Adding a custom library as a dependency in SAP Fiori

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a custom library com.foo.library I would like to include as a dependency of a Fiori-like app I have built.

[SAP Fiori Launchpad for Developers](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/a0b41949-b803-3210-6bba-dc97da1ac623?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&59511067181158) -> Best Practices for Launchpad Apps

> Declare configuration information, like the location of icons, and library dependencies in the component.js configuration file

makes sense, adding my library as a dependency would look like

```
    dependencies: {
        libs: ["sap.m", "sap.ui.layout", "com.foo.library"],
        components: []
    },
```

with Fiori you have the constraint that you must use relative paths.

eg for my dependency to work it must be found at

> /resources/com/foo/library

What are the steps for uploading a custom library into the ABAP SAPUI5 Repository and having it served with a relative path?

EDIT:

Currently i have the library loaded on Component.init using

```
 sap.ui.getCore().loadLibrary("com.foo.library", "absolute path to library");
```

it works, however I want to set the library as a dependency

```
ComponentMetadata.prototype._loadDependencies = function() {
..
            if (aLibraries) {
            jQuery.each(aLibraries, function(i, sLib) {
                jQuery.sap.log.info("Component \"" + that.getName() + 
                sap.ui.getCore().loadLibrary(sLib);
            });
        }
```

from code above I can see there is no option to pass in a url when the component loads the library dependencies, so i am assuming that the library has to be found relative to the resources

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("com.foo.library", "[YOUR URL]") in your application, then you can add the component and the prefix will be correctly resolved.

Comment: @sirion  I put the code at top and works well, thanks

Comment: But the last point in Fiori Launchpad for Developers says, "Avoid using jQuery.sap.registerModulePath inside your Component.js" !

Comment: @sakthi: Don't use it inside the Component - use it outside the component in the application that uses the component.

Comment: @sirion: But the question here is how do you add another component as a dependency to a component !

Comment: @sakthi q was about libraries,  if i share my component code, (1) i dont want the lib dependency inside the component, (2) the location to the library should be either constant eg always relative to /rescources or configurable, @ sirion's solution solved (1), get the dependency out of the Component, now need a solution (2) dont want to encourage customers to change code

Comment: @sakthi @ Jasper_07 it is the same for including custom components or libraries as depencies

Answer (score 4):

In your Fiori App:

1. Put your dependencie into the app descriptor (manifest.json) (or if no app descriptor used into the config inside the Component.js)

   ```
   dependencies: {
       libs: ["sap.m", "sap.ui.layout", "com.foo.library"],
       components: [com.foo.component]
   }
   ```
2. Let sap.ui.core know where to search for the namespace of your library.(Top of your Component.js)

   ```
   jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("com.foo", "/Path/on/the/server/");
   ```

And now you can use your dependencies. And here is why:

> Before a module is loaded, the longest registered prefix of its module
>   name is searched for and the associated URL prefix is used as a prefix
>   for the request URL. The remainder of the module name is attached to
>   the request URL by replacing dots ('.') with slashes ('/').
>
> The registration and search operates on full name segments only.

[Source: SAP UI5 API Documentation](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.registerModulePath)

Comment: In newer versions of SAPUI5, Modules get loaded if they are stated in the manifest. For older ones the dev has to manage that by herselve