# One app with multiple component.js: How to load shared modules?

Tags: sapui5

We have a SAPUI5 app in where we define multiple components (i.e., multiple Component.js files) each in a respective subfolder as direct child of the application root. The following image shows the project structure:

[image: Project layout]

Component 1 is specified as `com.test.component1`, component 2 as `com.test.component2`. Shared code is located in `root/shared` and defined as dependencies in the controllers of each component.

shared/Utils.js:

```
sap.ui.define([], function () {
    "use strict";

    return {...};
};
```

component1/controller/Controller1.js:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "test/shared/Utils"
], function (BaseController, Utils) {
    "use strict";
    // controller code

});
```

Running the index.html file locally (or in WebIDE) this all works, but the shared resources are not found when we try to integrate the different components into the Fiori Launchpad (it tries to load them from /resources/shared). We believe this has sth to do with the `data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"com.test": ""}` defined for bootstrapping which is missing either in the Component.js or the manifest.json file.

What's the right way to register the resource path `com/test/shared` for the individual components?

Comment: Similar problem can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016642/adding-a-custom-library-as-a-dependency-in-sap-fiori

Answer (score 3):

**Using a Component/library for your utilities**

The most obvious question I have here is: **If you use the component concept anyways why is your shared code not a component as well**. A Component does not necessarily have to have a UI, that's why there is a `UIComponent` and a simple `Component` to inherit from. You just load it as a dependency of component1/component2 like this:

```
... 
return Component.extend("com.test.Component1", {
  metadata: {
    name: "Component1",
    dependencies: {
      libs: [ "sap.m" ],
      components: [ "test.shared" ]
  },
...
```

If using a Component does not feel right for you, you could also package your utilities as a library. You might want to check out [grunt-openui5](https://github.com/SAP/grunt-openui5) that helps you building one.

**Loading external files without using Component/library concept**

Anyways defining a resourceroot on bootstrap is similar to a call to

```
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("test.shared", "/path/to/your/source");
```

You could register the module path of your shared modules in both of the components init. You will probably have to use an absolute path there since depending on the execution context (launchpad vs. standalone) the relative path might differ.

You could make the path 'relative' like this:

```
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("test.shared", jQuery.sap.getModulePath("com.test.Component1") +"/../shared);
```

Furhtermore if you want the shared resources to also benefit from cache busting you might want to use this afterwards:

```
sap.ui.core.AppCacheBuster.register(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("test.shared"));
```

Comment: Creating a component out of a bunch of util modules/classes doesn't feel right but might be a solution in the end. We've played around with `registerModulePath()` but as you mention the path is gonna be a problem: how can we guarantee portability if we need to specify an absolute path?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a UIComponent, a Utility Component would just inherit from Component. Of course it would be even better to make it a library. You can have a look into https://github.com/SAP/grunt-openui5 to build one. Path is still a problem... I'll try to find more info there

Comment: You coudl try this to have a relative path:     jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("test.shared", jQuery.sap.getModulePath("com.test.Component1") +"/../shared);

Comment: Can you point me to the component or library example? Not sure where to look for it in the context of grunt. I'll try using registerModulePath in combination with getModulePath.

Comment: Using getModulePath() referencing the parent directory does not work.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is by defining the `resourceRoots` attribute in the application descriptor (manifest.json):

```
{
    ...
    "sap.ui5": {
        ...
        "resourceRoots" : {
            "com.test.shared": "./../shared"
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

This works despite what's written in the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html):

> Map of URL locations keyed by a resource name prefix; only relative paths inside the component are allowed and no ".." characters