# How to load shared i18n files in multiple tiles(projects)?

Tags: sapui5

There are about ten tiles in our fiori app, and I put my shared files in /common, the following image shows the project structure(/analytics, /appsettings... are all tiles except /common):

[image]

Many i18n are the same between the tiles, so I want to maintain all i18n in /common.

In /analytic/webapp/Component.js, I defined i18n resource:

```
init: function() {
  UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

  // resourceroots is also defined in manifest.json,
  // why I defined resourceroots thrice is another topic, it's stupid, I know
  jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("myprojectcommon", "./../../common");
  jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("myproject.common", "/myproject/resources/common/");

  myprojectcommon.util.Utils.setComponent(this);

  var setComponentCommonResource = myprojectcommon.util.Utils.setCommonResource.bind(this);

  setComponentCommonResource();
}
```

/common/util/Utils:

```
setCommonResource: function() {
  var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
    bundleName: "myproject.common.i18n.i18n"
  });

  this.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
}
```

Now the common i18n is loaded, but i18n defined in manifest.json failed, such as

```
"sap.app": {
  "title": "{{appTitle}}",
  "description": "{{appDescription}}"
}
```

Which results:

[image]

What should I do?

There seems no API to set `title` in Component.js: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.UIComponent

Related questions: [One app with multiple component.js: How to load shared modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593261/one-app-with-multiple-component-js-how-to-load-shared-modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed by

```
"sap.app": {
  "i18n": "./../../common/i18n/i18n.properties"
}

"sap.ui5": {
  "resourceRoots": {
    "myprojectcommon": "./../../common/"
  },
  "models": {
    "i18n": {
      "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
      "settings": {
        "bundleName": "myprojectcommon.i18n.i18n"
      }
  },
}
```

below is how ui5 load i18n files location:
https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c014e24356497a44125c1dd5419fdf536119600e/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/Manifest.js#L200

Comment: Check out the `enchance` method on the resource bundle, so you can merge two i18n files: `this.getModel("i18n").enhance(globalModel.getResourceBundle());`.