# SAP Fiori can not create geocoder constructor on the first view call

Tags: google-maps, sapui5, geocoding

I would like to implement the GoogleMaps - GeoCoding API which should use the address attributes from a businesspartner to receive the related coordinates (lat,lng).

Please note: i extend an SAP Fiori App which is called by the SAP Fiori Lauchnpad, i don't develop a SAPUI5 from scratch.

But I have an issue. 
While i was loading the app, it's not possible to create the constructor of Geocoder API in the code.

> Error Message: "Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.Geocoder is not a
>   constructor"

I just want to execute the simple standard code in the controller:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
geocoder.geocode( { "address": address }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {

        var location = results[0].geometry.location;
        var lat  = location.lat();
        var lng  = location.lng();     

        alert("Latitude: " + lat);
        alert("Longitude: " + lng);
    }
});
```

Obviously i load the third party library (google maps - GEOCODING API) not.

But i don't find any good examples, how to load an external library in an SAP FIORI App. 
The approaches of the following link doesn't work: 
https://a.kabachnik.info/how-to-include-external-javascript-libraries-in-sap-ui5.html

Method 2 would be fine, but it doesn't work. 
My Current Project Structure is:

[image: Project Structure]

The peace of code for this approach brings no solution:

```
var theRootPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("cus.crm.myaccounts.zcrm_myacc_ext");
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath('lib.google.library', theRootPath + '/lib/google/library');

sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "lib/google/library"
], function(Controller, JSONModel, library) {
//call geocoding api
}
```

I am talking about a standard Fiori APP extension, so i don't use the index.html. I don't create a SAPUI5 App too... just for SAP FIORI EXTENSIONS.

I hope someone can help me how to integrate a third party library.

Comment: According to this blog [How to include third party libraries / modules in SAPUI5](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/04/30/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-modules-in-sapui5/)
you can include your external library in controller file (=Method 2). But apparently for some reason this didn’t work for you. Do you get an error message ? So instead you could take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016642/adding-a-custom-library-as-a-dependency-in-sap-fiori .
There, the library is defined in the manifest.json .

Comment: Thx, but i used another library from jasper. It works via manifest or sap.ui.core.loadLibrary(); 

In this library i can use the geocoding function which works very well.